# Unable to modify a slider height

Tags: css, slider, height

I recently bought a parallax template, and I am trying to make a website by modifying the code to my needs. The template I use have a full screen slider at the top of the one page parallax theme, marked as id="home". For some reason, this section is set to 100% height, but I want to change this.

In the template, the original code is as follows:

```
#home.home-fullscreenslider {
    background: url(../images/pattern.png);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And this initiates the slider:

```
<div id="home" class="home-fullscreenslider">
</div>
```

I deleted the height of the slider, so now I can fit the images to the screen properly. But the whole section is still at 100% height. I couldn't find any portion of the css code that dictates the height of #home. What do I need to do?

Comment: It would ideally be getting set using JavaScript ..

Comment: Would this be the code??  
function fullscreenImgHeight(){
 $('#home, .background-video').css({height:window_height});
/*    var headerH = $('nav').outerHeight();
          $("#home").css('marginBottom',-headerH);*/
    
   }
    
   fullscreenImgHeight();
    
    
    
   $(window).bind('resize',function() {
   
    fullscreenImgHeight();
    home_parallax();
       
   });  
   
};

Comment: can you post a link to demo site of the theme?